# What code is it neccesary to add to allow insert Components in different containers in XPM?

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

What code is it neccesary to add to allow insert Components in different containers in XPM?

I mean, I have a container Component which separates the content in two holes (separated in CME by a separator Component), like a grid. In XPM I would like to insert Components in one of them, not only above and below.

[image]

Is it possible to do it? Is it necessary to add some code to the separator element which allows me to insert Components in one of the holes?

I don't want to configure this with regions because I would like to insert any type of Components into the holes, and the regions restrict me this.

For the result shows in the image, I have I container Component, which paints the two holes, and one separator Component (dummy) which separates the content between them.

The technology I'm using is Compound Templating, calling Dreamweaver templates to write the HTML code.

What code do I need to enter to allow this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to give a bit more information about your setup here, like do you have XPM regions written out in your HTML, or do you just have a Component with a linked Component list in which you separate these two columns trhough a dummy separator Component, also what Templating technology do you use to generate the XPM markup in your pages, etc. etc.? Please **edit** your question and provide some more details.

Comment: I have added more information Bart. Thank you.

Comment: @Niclas Cedermalm created a flexible layouts solution for DXA similar to your requirements. However, his "containers" don't actually link to the Components but rather sit on the page above their "contained" Components. See https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-container-framework-for-flexible-layouts.

Answer (score 2):

XPM inline editing enables users to modify or move existing Components on a Web page, and it does this through the XPM markup. All of this is centered around a Page and its Component Presentations. By moving a Component on a Page, you essentially change the order of that Component Presentation on the Page. The details of implementing that in a Dreamweaver template are described here https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C032EB8B-E6A1-454E-B19A-46B458C1282B

If you want to move a Component Presentation in different dropzones, you have to implement XPM regions. More details are described here https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D99543D2-BAF8-4C9B-B177-27562A0E8293

That is all the theory, now lets look at some specifics around your question. You want to insert Components (a Component link in your case) either above or below the separator Component, using two different dropzones.

I don't know of a clean way to create these dropzones in XPM, since there is no functionality for that around Component links. The best suggestion I can give to implement this sort of behavior is to not use a container Component, and simply implement regions for the two different dropzones, and add the Components seperately on your Page. Examples of that is what we do in DXA with the 2 column region.

To solve the fact that you want freedom around what you can add in that regions, DXA publishes the region information based on Schema and Template information. If you add a new Schema to a Component Template marked with that region, it will add the combination of Schema and Template to that regions (when you republish the **Publish Settings** Page). See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-8714ED2D-4F98-4433-80DD-6A4FE2E6EC64 for some details. Changing your entire implementation over to DXA will be quite a change, but as a benefit you will get your web site implemented as an MVC web application, which is way more flexible when it comes to dynamics and a lot more natural way to develop and debug your implementation.